# RSA : Encrypt in Javascript and Decrypt in Php

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I've found many websites with something related to the subject line (few are in stackoverflow.com itself). However, unfortunately I couldnt get what I want.

What I want is - I've a public-private key pair ready with me. (something like this - http://andytson.com/blog/2009/07/php-public-key-cryptography-using-openssl/)

Now, I want a javascript page which will use this public key. And encrypt some data. This data is then passed on to the php page. And the php page decrypts the data.

So far, I've found few JS pages which does this stuff right from the scratch (i.e. from generating the key pair). Same story for php. But thats not of help to me.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Why would you do this? Couldn't you just use `https`?

Comment: This is a bad idea, for many reasons: JS does not have access to a true source of entropy, and there is no implementation of AES or RSA. So you'll most likely have to write it from scratch, which is a significant amount of work over just using SSL certificates.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld is wrong, there are absolutely js implementations of at least AES (like the [stanford crypto library](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/) ).  That said, you should probably still just use SSL

Comment: @PeterElliott: I meant native implementations.

Comment: Amm, I agree with you guys. The only problem is - this is required for an educational project. And for some (funny) reasons, they want it in this way. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Does http://area51.phpbb.com/phpBB/viewtopic.php?f=84&t=33024&start=0 do what you're wanting? Here's the stand-alone demo:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/dev/rsa/index.php

The source:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/dev/rsa/index.txt

Comment: please make your answer more than just a series of links to outside sources... answers should be able to stand more or less on their own.